# wifi not recognized unless restarted in archos 32

Tags: wi-fi, archos-gen8

Many times when I'm near a wifi network, my archos 32 won't recognize it. It shows no networks in the wireless settings and doesn't show alerts for available networks even when this alert is on in the settings. It would only recognize the network if I disable wifi and then reenable it.

Did that happen to anyone else? Any workaround?

Comment: [This thread](http://forum.archosfans.com/viewtopic.php?f=35&t=17511) on an archos 5 mentions turning off the "static IP" setting on the device. Does your device have that setting?

Comment: @gary, thanks but it's by default off, and it's also off in my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a power-saving strategy, radio chipsets can sleep -- meaning they stop actively listening for a wi-fi network to connect to -- when they are out of range of any network, and will wake up to search for a network once every few minutes.

It may simply be that the radio on your Android is doing this, and that you haven't waited long enough for it to wake up once you come back in range of a wi-fi network.

A quick search tells me there's a *Powersave disabled* setting in the wi-fi settings on the Archos that might help.

Answer (score 0):

My 32 suffers from various wifi and bluetooth issues, dropping both connections. starting and stopping. Connecting to wifi but not routing packets. Connecting to bluetooth headset but no audio. I have to fuss with it all the time.